# ViewPager in RecyclerView does'nt show from second rows

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I want to add ViewPager with tablayout in my RecyclerView row. But fragment I add in ViewPager just show in firts row, from second row, just TabLayout show, fragment in ViewPager not show. I read and found that I need set ID for each ViewPager. ViewPager does not allow sharing of the id in the same fragment, even if it is part of a recyclerview context. But I don'nt know how to do that. Anyone can show me what exactly step I need to do or another method ? Thanks you very much.
Code my RecyclerView Adapter
public class ListArtifactsAdapter extends

```
RecyclerView.Adapter<ListArtifactsAdapter.ListArtifactsViewHolder>
{
    private List<Artifact> artifacts;
    private Context  context;
    public static class ListArtifactsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView;
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public ViewPager mViewPager;
        public TabLayout mTabLayout;
        public ListArtifactsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
            mImageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            View v = itemView.findViewById(R.id.function_tab);
            mViewPager = (ViewPager)v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mTabLayout = (TabLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        }
    }
    public ListArtifactsAdapter(List<Artifact> artifacts, Context context){
        this.artifacts = artifacts;
        this.context  = context;
    }
    @Override
    public ListArtifactsAdapter.ListArtifactsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ListArtifactsViewHolder vh = new ListArtifactsViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_demo, parent, false));
        return vh;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ListArtifactsAdapter.ListArtifactsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Artifact artifact = artifacts.get(position);
        holder.mTextView.setText(artifact.getName());
        holder.mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.add);
        holder.mViewPager.setAdapter(new ArtifactInformationAdapter(((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager(), artifact.getAudio(), artifact.getTranscript()));
        holder.mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(holder.mViewPager);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return artifacts.size();
    }
}
```

My ViewPager Adapter

```
public class ArtifactInformationAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private  List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private  List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArtifactInformationAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager,String audio, String transcript) {
        super(fragmentManager);

        mFragmentList.add(AudioFragment.newInstance(audio));
        mFragmentList.add(TranscriptFragment.newInstance(transcript));
        mFragmentTitleList.add("Audio");
        mFragmentTitleList.add("Transcript");
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
           return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: try passing getChildFragmentManger() instead of getSupportFragmentManger() then tell me what happens

Comment: My RecyclerView in activity, so I dont have a Fragment for method getChildFragmentManger().